# Compare String with Number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to compare the contents of a text file with a hard number with no success:

```
string version = File.ReadAllText("C:\\version.txt");

if (version > 1)
{
   MessageBox.Show("Update Available!");
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Will the content of the text file *always* be an integer? Will it definitely not have any linebreaks etc?

Comment: Yea, it will always have a number on the 1st line. No other lines.

Comment: What does the error message tell you? :P

Comment: Side note: please don't add following text to your posts - new here, new to language XXX, thank you, and similar phrases not directly related to your problem. Instead add detailed error messages/call stack/code. Try to avoid unrelated code in sample (i.e. this one really need `string version = "2";` instead of reading from file).

Comment: 1 is not really that hard number :), I'd worry about 13.

Comment: Sorry for the extra comments - new here :).  Ha, Alexei, 13 isn't so bad. Its 42 that scares me :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare a string with a number, you have to parse it first. You can use `int.Parse` or [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)(to check if the format is valid):

```
int number;
if(int.TryParse(version, out number) && number > 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Update Available!");
}
```

If the number can also be `1.23` you can use `double.Parse` or `decimal.Parse`.

Comment: MessageBox.Show("Update Available!") missing the ; at the end?

Answer (score 3):

You have to parse version:

```
if (int.Parse(version) > 1)
{

}
```

Or the other way:

```
if(version.ToString() > "1")
{ 
   //be careful with this as it compares two numbers using dictionary sort, e.g. "200" is less than "3"
}
```

C# is a strongly typed language. You can't perform operations on incompatible types. Int and string aren't compatible so you have to convert one to the other for your operation to work.

Comment: It'd be worth adding the alternative of casting the int to a string (just for completeness) and mentioning some ways the cast could fail.